# Custom fieldtype: tag pair and replace_tag_catchall()

Tags: add-on-development, custom-fields, fieldtype

I'm building a new fieldtype which should be used with:

- single tag:

  {myfield}

...which correctly calls replace_tag() method

- single tag with modifier:

  {myfield:modifier}

...which correctly calls replace_tag_catchall()

- tag pair:

  {myfield}{somedata}{/myfield}

...which correctly calls replace_tag()

- but I also need tag pair with modifier:

  {myfield:modifier}{somedata}{/myfield:modifier}

...which should call replace_tag_catchall(), but it's not calling anything.

[The documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/fieldtypes.html#creating-multiple-rendering-options) is relatively clear that it should work.

Any idea how I can make the miracle happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fieldtype tag pairs with modifiers SHOULD NOT contain the modifier in the closing tag.

Wrong:

```
{myfield:modifier}{somedata}{/myfield:modifier}
```

Right:

```
{myfield:modifier}{somedata}{/myfield}
```

Comment: And sadly, Matrix, as the Murphy law applies, requires that the closing tag contains the modifier... And it works with tags pairs but not with single tags. Well, I need a beer...